# How to create a material that is not affected by light? (Blender 4.0, Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Blender 4.0, Cycles. How to create a material that is not affected by light? I would like to make this part not affected by light

Blender file: [DOWNLOAD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YWwV1YbKcLE0C_sLuVc1sOfqFam12RMc/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: You might want to give more context about what you are trying to achieve, so even if it's not 100% possible ,there are probably a work around

Comment: If you can see it, it's affected by light. I'm guessing you mean 'not affected by direct light from source X' ?

Comment: You could use the new Light Linking but the object won't receive anymore light from the light

Answer (score 1):

If we express the problem differently, the solution becomes apparent. The areas of the floor that receive light are the ones that do not have an object casting shadows on them. Therefore, our objective is to add an invisible object that will only cast shadows there. This kind of object is often called a *shadow caster*.

Its setup is simple. You just need to uncheck its *Ray Visibility* to everything except Shadows. This can be found in the *Object Properties* under *Visibility*.

[image: Shadow Caster]

---

**Edit:** Screenshots showing the effect of the shadow caster and the modified blend file are attached below.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Blend file:

[image]

Comment: It didn't help, can you show it in my blender file? I would like to hide lighting for the floor
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YWwV1YbKcLE0C_sLuVc1sOfqFam12RMc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I updated my answer.